Вопрос про чтение файлов в byte[]
Вопрос состоит в следующем:
Если я читаю файл File.ReadAllBytes в byte[], то каждый элемент массива имеет разное число.
Мне интересно, а почему байтовое представление файла именно такое, а не все элементы массива = 255, кроме скажем последнего?
Файл представлял из себя exe рандомной программы.
Вы хотите сказать, что каждый элемент текстового файла- это код 1-го символа?

Какие данные в файл записаны, такие и байты будут. Если там текст в UTF, то будут коды символов в UTF. Почему в массиве должны получиться одинаковые байты по-вашему - там одинаковые символы весь файл идут, или что? Что у вас в этом файле вообще записано было, прежде всего?

Нет. Байт это байт. А сколько байтов составляет один символ - зависит от кодировки.

«почему байтовое представление файла именно такое» / «exe рандомной программы» — https://habr.com/ru/articles/266831/

А почему у exe-файла должны быть одинаковые байты? Там же, по крайней мере, код, т.е. разные символы, а значит разные байты. А вообще любой исполняемый файл имеет PE-формат, там куча разных служебных данных, а первые два байта должны быть только 77, 90 ("MZ"), иначе он не загрузится.
